# Passing Objects as Props Inline

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

Is something like this possible in Svelte?

```
<CustomElement props={ {akey: `value`, bkey: `value`} }></CustomElement>
```

I know I can pass the object if I have defined it in the script, but some components I just need to send a couple static properties.

Comment: Should `CustomElement` imply that the compilation flag for custom elements is used and that this code appears in plain HTML and not a Svelte file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Svelte files this is possible.
In HTML with components compiled to custom elements this probably will not work, as all HTML attributes are strings.